# How to clear all the values of a Form before starting new unit test case in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Form which has around 10 to 12 fields, i know individually, how to clear the fields, but is there any way that, we can clear all the fields in form at once in selenium using python. Please give me an idea of how to solve this.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Thank You Jeff, For correcting me

Answer (score 0):

In java this can be done using `reset()` method of `javascript` forms:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("document.getElementById('" + yourFormIDHere + "').reset();");
```

and in Python this can be done as follows:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('" + yourFormIDHere + "').reset();");
```

Comment: Hi Kushal, Thank you for helping me, I tried with reset but no-luck, it throws attribute error as,  "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'reset' ". Please help me, how to debug this

Comment: are you passing id for a <form> cause it will work with only <form> Objects.